# sql query - how to retain all decimal places in a sum value when collating multiple outputs into one

Tags: sql, format, decimal, truncated

I am using SQL Server Management Studio to extract summaries of data from multiple sources and collate them into one output. The final output consists of several calculated measures per dimension.

One of the sources has data with multiple decimal places, and I need to retain all of them in the final output. When I run the query for that source alone, the output includes all the decimal places - it's not rounded or truncated. But when I combine it with a summary for another source that doesn't have decimals, all of the decimal places are truncated.

I've tried to format/cast/convert but I don't know if I'm getting the syntax right. An example of my query looks like this:

```
select month
,sum (value_with_decimals) as denominator
into #summary_table
from source.dbo.one
group by month;

go

insert into #summary_table

select month
,sum (value_without_decimals) as denominator
from source.dbo.two
group by month

go

select month
sum (denominator)
from #summary_table
group by month;

go

drop table #summary_table

go
```

In the final summary, the decimals from source.dbo.one are gone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the datatype of the column "value_with_decimals" in the "source.dbo.one" and the datatype of that column in the  #Summary table

Comment: You could use the cast() function and use the datatype of the column based on which you want to retain the decimals. More details on cast function here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp

Comment: **what is the datatype of the column "value_with_decimals" in the "source.dbo.one" and the datatype of that column in the #Summary table** 

the datatype of "value_with_decimals" is (float). I don't know how to check what it is in the #summary table, because it's a temporary table that I've made just for the purpose of collating all of my extracts into one. it's not a table saved in the data warehouse.

Also, the "value_with_decimals" is the only measure that I sum in my query, the rest of the measures are either count or sum(case when then 1 else 0) examples.

Comment: Thank you S B and Dennis, I used cast(sum("value_without_decimals") as float) as denominator and it worked.

Cheers! Ruth

Answer (score 0):

Thank you S B and Dennis, I used cast(sum("value_without_decimals") as float) as denominator and it worked. Cheers! Ruth